# How can we fire onchange handler when we dynamically change component v.value?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I'm trying to build a simple component:

**testComponent.cmp**

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" 
                                  objectApiName="Contact"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}" > 

   <lightning:inputField aura:id="fAcc" fieldName="AccountId" onchange="{! c.onAccountChange}" />

</lightning:recordEditForm>

<lightning:button aura:id="btnChange" label="Change" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.fireOnChange}" />
```

**testComponentController.js**

```
({
    fireOnChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("fAcc").set("v.value", '00190000009LKcJAAW');
    },
    onAccountChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('test here if Account field is changed programatically');
    }
})
```

Now, if I manually pick an Account, the `onAccountChange` handler gets fired, but it does not fire when I change value of the field using a Button.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: this might be useful --> [aura:valueChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm)

Comment: I don't think this will work. the `lightning:inputField` is bind to a field name, and there is not concrete sObject or it's field to bind a change attribute to.

Comment: a silly workaround, why not move the onAccountchange function/logic to the helper and call the onAccountchangehelper() method from the fireOnchange function

Comment: actually that is the workaround I had done. Was just curious why it wasn't called automatically or how do we initiate a manual onchange event bound on an input. Could this be a Bug?